# Earliest use of an asterisk (*) to indicate a zero-to-many character wildcard?

Tags: etymology

I was explaining to someone what the * in "trans*" means (zero-to-many wildcard. In this case, it's used to refer to both "transexual" and "transgender" people with the same word), and another friend chimed in saying it came from computer programming. While I could tell them it was used in operating systems such as DOS and Unix before that, I couldn't say whether it came from computer culture or appeared before that. It seems reasonable that there would have been use for it, but a different character may easily have been chosen.

*What is the earliest recorded instance of an asterisk being used as a zero-to-many character wildcard?*

Note: I'm not referring to masks such as "f*ck". That is a different concept, in that it's a replacement of exactly one character, and is referring to only a single word.

Comment: It was invented by Stephen Kleene around 1956 as part of the specifications for [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression); it's called the ["Kleene star" or the "Kleene closure"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not that familiar with regex. It looks like you give the star a set of possibilities and ask for all combinations, rather than having it act as a total wildcard. But "trans*" isn't a total wildcard either. So it's probably a completely valid answer. Why did you make it a comment instead?

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir Technically, the Kleene star operator applies to the previous atom.  What you are looking at is a shortcut used in filename wildcard expansions. Your `trans*` is really `^trans.*$` using real regexes, because the star applies to the previous dot.

Comment: Since I assume that most people would not expect _trans*_ to include **transport**, **transubstantiation** or even **transition**; its claimed connection to a multi-character wildcard seems rather forced.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is NOT about "English". Basically, what @Fortiter said - it's just a **very** loose extension of a computer filename convention.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I see what you mean. I had a lot of trouble figuring out where to ask the question, and I couldn't find the information I wanted through my own searches. Is there any way to improve the question, or should it be closed?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. I don't think I've heard it outside a CS/computer-related context, but if it is used as OP suggests, then isn't it a neologosim (through re-purposing)? (And hence, as on-topic as a question about "lol", or "-dar" as in "gaydar")   @AlbeyAmakiir, I think it would improve the question if you could provide some examples of this "trans*" usage, or other usages of the 'Kleene star' outside of computing.   (And +1 to JL, as usual. Could/should be an answer.)

Comment: @hunter2: By that logic, a question about the earliest use (and current scope) of, say, the [mathematical symbol Sigma (**∑** = sum of all values in range of series)](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm) would be On Topic. But I don't think it is, and I think it's irrelevant that there *might* be another SO site where such a question *might* be on topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't follow. I get why you say that that Sigma should be Off-T. I get why the 'Kleene star' would be Off for the same reason *if* it's used the way I know. But it seems to me that if it's used in the way the OP says, it's no longer esoteric to CS, and may be On-T here. / If it's only used in 'trans*' discussions amongst CS folk, that's not new, it's group jargon (not yet included in the broader language). Admittedly, if it's used specifically in 'trans*' talk outside of CS, but that's the *only* place it's used outside of CS-ish context, then it might be still too jargon-y.

Comment: Also, I'm not such an expert on what's On- or Off- here. (And I find each of these interesting, whether or not they're On). Also it's late for me and the weekend is here ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another StackExchange site: MIGRATE TO STACKOVERFLOW!

Comment: @hunter2: I've never encountered **trans[asterisk]** used to mean **transgender** (to be honest, I thought **transgender** already *was* the umbrella term for transexuals, transvestites, etc.). But regardless of that I think it would be OT here because it's essentially part of the "language of mathematics / computer science" symbol set. If it *is* used with any currency outside those contexts, that wouldn't be peculiar to ***English*** - it would in principle apply to any "natural language".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I voted to close using that same rationale. What I'm seeing after research though is that **trans*** seems to be an accepted usage in English prose on the web. Google [ trans asterisk ] to see what I mean. I'd take that closevote back if I could.

Comment: I agree with @MετάEd: there is an on-topic question here, although some editing could make that clearer. I don't have time to edit it myself, but I'm thinking the phrase "zero-to-many" is throwing people off, because it sounds so computer-specific.

Comment: @FumbleFingers agreed on the first sentence of your comment. It was a hypothetical about the situation being as MετάEd has now shown it to be. Your latter point ('any NL') is trickier; maybe only if we could demonstrate a non-English instance. I guess *comparing* the migration of this usage into English v. into other NLs would be an interesting question on Linguistics.SE

Comment: @hunter2: My position is pretty much summed up by [the first comment here](http://itspronouncedmetrosexual.com/2012/05/what-does-the-asterisk-in-trans-stand-for/): *Oh for Pete's sake! I have been a computer user for over thirty years and should have at least had some inkling that that's what it might have been. As it is, I have on so many occasions scrolled down to the bottom of blog posts to see what footnote the author is referencing with that fucking asterisk. When there were none [I realised it's just] one of those affectations of the social-justice blogosphere that I wasn't privy to.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sure, and I still agree with you on the subject. To be very clear: 0) I had not heard/seen this usage before this question-post. 1)I am familiar with the computing use, and understand how *that* would be off-topic. 2) If I could bar all three from the language (this usage of the asterisk, and anything relating to 'lol' or 'gaydar'), I would. ... That said, given what we now know, *if* 'lol' and 'gaydar' are *on*-topic here, then I think this star-thing must be too.

Comment: There's also a 3) in there about 'social justice linguistics', but I'll leave it (mostly).  Also, probably should have taken this to Meta a few comments ago.

Comment: @hunter2: Well, I have to admit that comment I linked to above doesn't *exactly* reflect my position. I don't recall seeing this "trans-asterisk" usage before - but having a computing background myself, I like to think I'd have understood it straight away, and not gone looking for the relevant footnote. And I don't particularly object to it either. It's just one of those quirky habits like when people hold up two fingers on each hand as they say some particular word, to signify it's "in quotes". It's related to language, but it's not what I would call **English Language and Usage**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now you're OK with air quotes? Ugh, ugh I say. (Half-kidding/in fun.)   IDK, man.  Meta?   http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/when-are-neologisms-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you ask about, *trans**, appears to be a new word in written English. A Google search for [`trans asterisk`] returns many examples of usage.

As a wildcard expression, the term would simply represent all words beginning with *trans*. But in written text having to do with sexuality, it means “the entire gender identity spectrum”, by extension from individual words such as *transsexual*, *transgender*, and *transvestite*. The term uses the asterisk as a wildcard to symbolize *all* gender identities and possibilities.

It’s not clear how *trans** is being pronounced; two possibilities I have seen online are “trans asterisk” and “trans anything”.

The asterisk wildcard character used in the term does predate DOS and UNIX. It descends from the Multics asterisk wildcard character, known as a *star name* or the *star convention*.¹

> ### Notes
>
> 1. History of the asterisk wildcard character leading up to DOS and UNIX (and beyond):
>
> *TOPS-10 syntax (precursor of MS-DOS)*
>
> The TOPS-10 operating system took the asterisk to mean *all*. It would be used in place of an entire filename, extension, user number, or group number. For example, `*.PL1` stands for all filenames with extension `PL1`. The asterisk was used alone, never combined with other characters, so you could not write `A*.PL1`. (Technically, the TOPS-10 asterisk in place of a filename is exactly equivalent to six question marks: `??????`. Filenames were fixed at six characters wide. The question mark stands for any single character in its position.)
>
> Later DEC operating systems, such as DOS-BATCH, RSTS, and RSX, inherited this syntax. CP/M (or possibly Commodore DOS before it) took its wildcard syntax from RSTS, and CP/M’s syntax was emulated by MS-DOS.
>
> *Multics syntax (precursor of UNIX and modern Microsoft Windows)*
>
> The GE Multics operating system supported a more flexible syntax: the asterisk matched any number of characters in a name component, and could be combined with other characters. For example, `a*.pl1` stands for all filenames whose first component starts with `a` and whose second component is `pl1`. UNIX took its wildcard syntax from Multics but did away with components, treating the period as an ordinary character in the filename. In UNIX, `a*pl1` stands for all filenames beginning with `a` and ending with `pl1`.
>
> The last major DEC operating system, VAX/VMS, dropped the legacy DEC syntax in favor of the Multics syntax. Influenced by VAX/VMS, Microsoft Windows NT (the ancestor of 2000, XP, Vista, 7, and 8) did the same.
>
> *Relationship to Kleene star*
>
> The asterisk wildcard character may have been inspired by the Kleene star used in regular expressions, but I have been unable to find any explanation of its origins in either TOPS-10 or Multics so I cannot confirm that idea. There is a family resemblance between the two, but they are different. The Kleene star is a decade older and more flexible than the two asterisk syntaxes discussed above. It takes as an argument a set of elements, and means a name composed of 0 or more of those elements. For example, `(ab|cde)*` stands for all names which are combinations of the elements `ab` and `cde` (including the empty string): `ab`, `cdeabcde`, etc.

Comment: Have never encountered the term "trans*" before but would guess it is pronounced "trans-star".

Comment: @AllInOne It's just pronounced "trans".

Comment: Does “the entire gender identity spectrum” mean that this applies evenly across that spectrum? Does it include 'straight'/'heteronormative'? Or, is does it imply 'traditionally underrepresented orientations'/GLBT people/issues? (Sorry if these are not the preferred nomenclature in this context.)  So, is the phrase "trans* topics" closer to "gender and orientation topics" or "GLBT topics"?

Comment: @hunter2 Actually, as I've seen it used, it's only ever referred to people who's gender identity and physical sex are different, or who's gender identity or physical sex has changed in some way. I'm... a little fuzzy on the definitions myself, as it doesn't directly relate to me. It's still a wider term than any of the terms it covers, but it's more limited than LGBT (which, itself, only covers the well known terms, the last one being whichever trans* term the reader thinks of at the time).

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir Got it. Makes sense.